# Interaction term in the Hamiltonian of transverse-field Ising model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, interactions, ising-model, spin-models

I got a question about [quantum transverse-field Ising model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse-field_Ising_model).  The Hamiltonian has two terms which are external field term and interaction term. Why are there only $Z$-$Z$ interactions between neighboring spins where $Z$ represents Pauli $Z$ operator? How about $X$-$X$ and $Y$-$Y$ interactions where $X$ and $Y$ represent Pauli $X$ operator and Pauli $Y$ operator respectively? From the point of view of physics, if we placed two spin 1/2 particles close to each other, do their spins interact only in one direction (e.g. along the $z$-axis)? If they also interact in other directions, why aren't this considered in the setup of transverse-field Ising model?

Comment: The quantum Ising model has only $Z-Z$ interaction because it is the quantum version of the classical Ising model. It is just a model. You can include $X-X$ and $Y-Y$ interactions but then your model will not be called "Ising" but rather "Heisenberg" model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_Heisenberg_model). There is a lot of research on the Heisenberg model, and in fact it is the first model the was solved using the Bethe *ansatz* method, originally by Hans Bethe in the 1930s

Comment: @yyy That should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @yyy Thanks for your clear explanation!